# Что использовать для изменения переменной из недр потока?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Такая проблема: есть отдельный модуль. В нем класс, представляющий собой поток - `threading.Thread`. В нем переопределен метод `run()`. В нем выполняется некий код. Мне нужно, чтобы поток каким-то "чудом" либо возвращал полученное в `run()` значение, либо изменял переменную, которую ему передают. Использовать глобальную переменную не самый лучший выход - во-первых потому что глобальная, во-вторых потому что не красиво определять переменную модуля и ее уже использовать. И то лишь раз.

На данный момент я склоняюсь к варианту с использованием коллбеков - передать в класс функцию, которую он вызовет по окончанию `run()` и в нее передаст нужные данные. В теории способ рабочий, но может есть какой-то более "красивый" способ? А то я чую, что это будет говнокод (как и все мои работы, впрочем).

Язык: Python

Upd: Ах, да, забыл про пример)
Код:

```
class Dscan_Recon(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mx = 0
        self.my = 0

    def run(self):

        for i in range(5, -1, -1):
            print("[LOG] Задержка перед определением верхней-левой точки: "+str(i)+"s.")
            time.sleep(1)
            
        ovx1, ovy1 = wapi.GetCursorPos()
        print("[LOG] Координаты верхней-левой точки: X: "+str(ovx1)+" Y: "+str(ovy1))

        for i in range(5, -1, -1):
            print("[LOG] Задержка перед определением верхней-левой точки: "+str(i)+"s.")
            time.sleep(1)

        ovx2, ovy2 = wapi.GetCursorPos()
        print("[LOG] Координаты нижней-правой точки: X: "+str(ovx2)+" Y: "+str(ovy2))

        x1, y1, _, _ = self.get_window_metrics(wHndl)
        ovx1, ovy1, ovx2, ovy2 = ovx1-x1, ovy1-y1, ovx2-x1, ovy2-y1
```

Это класс с потоком. Мне нужно, чтобы он возвращал эти 4 значения в конце. Т.е. 2 точки на экране. Мне кажется, что коллбек здесь лучше всего подойдет. Но так ли это? Или может есть что-то более удобное?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Забыл, подправил

Comment: Это не похоже на минимально-воспроизводимый пример. 
В каких местах у вас длительный процесс ? 
Что такое `wapi.GetCursorPos()` ?
Что такое `self.get_window_metrics(wHndl)` ?
Используете ли вы PyQt ?

Comment: @S.Nick это  из winapi все

Comment: Это не PyQt5. Это win32api из PyWin

Answer (score 2):

Ещё как вариант

```
class Dscan_Recon(Thread):
    def __init__(self): 
           super().__init__() 
           ... 
           self.result = None

    def run(self):
           ... 
           self.result =... 

t = Dscan_Recon() 
t.start()
t.join()
r = t.result
```

Comment: Тогда теряется вообще весь смысл потока. Ведь основной скрипт стоит на месте. Мне же нужно псевдопараллельное выполнение

Comment: @CSharpLooser join и start могут быть в разных функциях или между ними можно сделато что-то ещё. Колбэк же не сработает в Qt - работа с интерфейсом возможна только в главном треде. Там нужны сигналы и слоты. Я просто привел вариант который может быть полезен. Ответ может остаться без галки.